# 'typings install moment' fails for Aurelia

Tags: momentjs, aurelia, typescript-typings

It's simple: installing moment via Typings fails:

```
Typings install moment --save
```

with 'Unable to find "moment" ("npm") in the registry...' In other posts some people to say to use '--ambient' like so:

```
Typings install --ambient moment --save
```

while this works, it corrupts my Aurelia module ts files. It changes

```
export * from '~aurelia....'
```

to

```
import alias = requires('~aurelia....') 
export = alias
```

It does this in EVERY module file and this makes the app fail b/c it no longer recognizes the Aurelia framework modules. So the --ambient flag is bad and I need to just install the basic moment.d.ts file via Typings.

Any ideas how to get Typings to install moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`typings install dt~moment --global --save`

For more see [Typings docs](https://github.com/typings/typings)

Comment: This is interesting. It does find the moment library doing this, so that's a start, but when it updates the aurelia app it gets an error in index.d.ts. It appears the the Aurelia integration isn't working. Says it can't find namespace moment:  declare var moment: moment.MomentStatic;

Comment: Sorry dude, I can't help you with this comment. Not enough info. Try searching for "how to use typings."

Comment: I finally jumped through enough hoops to get it working. I wrote a blog post here:  http://www.aureliajsrocks.com/typescript-moment-jspm-installation/

Comment: great! although, tsd is deprecated in favor of typings. you're right to note that you should not use the ambient flag for aurelia libraries. you can resolve the aurelia-framework autoinject problem by using `typings install github:aurelia/framework`, though. anyway, if this answer was helpful, please upvote and accept it